# Python SSH script to extract Cisco switches information in preparation for network migration

Tags: python, ssh

I have a list of Cisco Nexus5548 IP addresses and FQDNs.  Could you please help with a Python script to SSH to each and extract the following in order to import it into Excel column format:

IP  Name    Port Number Port Description    Port Type   Vlans   Optic Type  Medium Type
172.x.x.x   hqcr1-swx-x E1/x    The actual port description (Access or Trunk)   300-305,2276,…  1g-sr, 10g-sr, 1g-glct  (copper fiber, or twinax)

This is what I have so far:

```
import paramiko, getpass, time

devices = {'device1': {'ip': 'xx.xx.xx.xx'}} 
           'device2': {'ip': 'xx.xx.xx.xx'}}
commands = ['show version\n', 'show run\n']

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.getpass('Password: ')

max_buffer = 65535

def clear_buffer(connection):
    if connection.recv_ready():
        return connection.recv(max_buffer)

# Starts the loop for devices
for device in devices.keys(): 
    outputFileName = device + '_output.txt'
    connection = paramiko.SSHClient()
    connection.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    connection.connect(devices[device]['ip'], username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    new_connection = connection.invoke_shell()
    output = clear_buffer(new_connection)
    time.sleep(2)
    new_connection.send("terminal length 0\n")
    output = clear_buffer(new_connection)
    with open(outputFileName, 'wb') as f:
        for command in commands:
            new_connection.send(command)
            time.sleep(2)
            output = new_connection.recv(max_buffer)
            print(output)
            f.write(output)

new_connection.close()
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: could you describe what you've tried so far?  where does the list of switches come from?  the `subprocess` module is good for invoking `ssh` or you could use `paramiko` if you want/need more control

Comment: The list of IPs and FQDNs comes from Cisco Prime Infrastructure. This is what I have and would like to somehow track all desired parameters for every single switch in some sort of a dictionary.

Comment: The list of IPs comes from Cisco Prime Infrastructure.  I am using paramiko and currently have a script but the comment field to small to past the entire script.

Comment: maybe use something like SNMP instead?  there's a `pysnmp` library if you want to use python

Comment: I would like to capture the desired parameters for each switches in some sort of a dictionary.

Comment: yes, python would let you do that.  I'm not going to write your code for you!  there are lots of tutorials around the internet if you want to learn…

Comment: Do you have a sample code using pysnmp library?

Comment: @theotherswan: Welcome to Stack Overflow! However, your question isn't suitable here. There are multiple reasons, but for a start, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score -1):

have you tried using `exec_command` on the `SSHClient`?  not sure how Cisco boxes play with opening/closing multiple channels, but it seems as though it might help separate the output from each command up.

I'd do something like:

```
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

def process_devices(devices, connect_args, commands):
    with SSHClient() as client:
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())

        for device in devices:
            client.connect(device, **connect_args)

            cmdout = []
            for cmd in commands:
                stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd, timeout=10)
                cmdout.append((stdout.read(), stderr.read()))

            yield (device, cmdout)
```

which is useful for things like:

```
from getpass import getpass

devices = [
    '127.0.0.1',
]

connect_args = dict(
    username='smason',
    password=getpass("Password: "),
)

commands = [
    "echo hello world",
    "date",
]

for dev, cmdout in process_devices(devices, connect_args, commands):
    print(f"{dev}: {cmdout}")
```

you can of course put the output from `process_devices` directly into a `dict` if you want, it's an iterator that returns appropriate pairs